# C++17 initializing base class constructor using drived class constants as the paramers of the base class constructor

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Now before  i continue with the question i would like to state  i have read that that const values, references must be initialized in the initialization list of the constructor. However i still  need clarification in this case.

Here is a realy simple inheritance example with code attached https://github.com/courteous/constrcutorChaining

class F : E

class E : D

class D : C

class C : B

class B : A

The  only spcecific part here is that base class "A"  inherits publicly from a template "enable_shared_from_this"

Now the different behavior i observe is  i.e. when I create  a share pointer of "E"  then the  "parameterized D constructor called : 17" is being called

```
shared_ptr<E> eInstance = make_shared<E>();

default A constructor called
default B constructor called
default C constructor called
parameterized D constructor called : 5
default E constructor called
```

however if i create a shared pointer of class F like that

```
shared_ptr<F> fInstance = make_shared<F>();

default A constructor called
default B constructor called
default C constructor called
default D constructor called
default E constructor called
default F constructor called
```

then the default E constructor is called  Why is that in this case.

I have found other answers in Stackoverflow that refere to the problem of the copy constructor not beein implemented i.e.

[Default constructor called instead of parametrized constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690285/default-constructor-called-instead-of-parametrized-constructor)

but in this case no cloning or coping is beeing done i.e. a simple base constructor explicitelly called.

The expected behavior here should be that the parameterized class D constructor should always be called, but that is not the case when I create a shared pointer of F. Can someone tell me why and what would be the right approach toforce class F to take the path 
 F-> "default constructor" E->"default constructor " ->"parameterized D constructor called : 17".

The interesting classes in this case are F, E and D

F.h

```
#ifndef _F_
#define _F_

#include "E.h"

#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace constructroTest
    {

    class F : public virtual E {


    public:
        static const uint16_t fixedLength;

        explicit F();
        virtual ~F();

protected:
        shared_ptr<F> shared_from_this()
            {
            return dynamic_pointer_cast<F>(E::shared_from_this());
            }
        };

    }


#endif  //#ifndef _F_
```

E.h

```
#ifndef _E_
#define _E_

#include "D.h"

#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace constructroTest
    {

    class E : public virtual D
        {

    public:
        static const uint16_t fixedLength;

        explicit E();
        virtual ~E();

protected:
        shared_ptr<E> shared_from_this()
            {
            return dynamic_pointer_cast<E>(D::shared_from_this());
            }
        };

    }

#endif  //#ifndef _E_
```

D.h

```
#ifndef _D_
#define _D_

#include "C.h"
#include <string>
#include <memory>


namespace constructroTest
    {

    class D : public virtual C
        {


    public:
        static const uint16_t fixedLength;


        explicit D();
        virtual ~D();


        explicit D(uint16_t dArgument);


protected:
        shared_ptr<D> shared_from_this()
            {
            return dynamic_pointer_cast<D>(C::shared_from_this());
            }
        };

    }


#endif  //#ifndef _D_
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please note that all symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_D_`) are *reserved*. You should not define such symbols yourself. See e.g. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more details.

Comment: thanks  I will consider this ,, in fact very good point

Comment: For MCVE, you might get rid of A, B, C (). Provide constructor. (During minimization of example, you might also notice that `shared_from_this` stuff were unneeded)

Comment: you are right A B and C are not needed in this case. I will cut them off. However i was not sure about shared_from_this thus included it ,, but can remove that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of **virtual inheritance**, only the most derived class initializes the virtual base class.

So in

```
shared_ptr<E> eInstance = make_shared<E>();
```

virtual base `D` is build from `E`

Whereas, in

```
shared_ptr<F> eInstance = make_shared<F>();
```

virtual base `D` is build from `F` ("ignoring" `E`).

Comment: thank you for the quick replay. What would be the right way to enforce the behavior where parameterized D constructor will be called even if virtual inheritance is used since the virtual inheritance is needed in my case not in the case of this example.

Comment: did you made a mistake by making bough instance " shared_ptr<E> eInstance = make_shared<E>();  " ? or was that deliberate?

Comment: @Tito: typo fixed -> `make_shared<F>` not `E` in last case,

Comment: is there a way to enforce the behavior of always calling the parameterized D constructor even if virtual inheritance is used ?

Comment: Jarod32  i am trying to follow here. I am confused why this is still happening if i am explicitly telling in Class F that it needs to call his base class i.e. "F::F() : E()" . If D is constructed from E the by calling the default constructor of E, D parameterized should get executed.

Comment: You need `F() : D(42), E() {}`. You might remove/`=delete` default `D` constructor to force to only use the constructor taking parameter.